# Generate a jQCloud array from a PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, laravel

I'm using the jQCloud utility to generate a word cloud but i can´t do it.

Here´s my controller´s code:

```
public function consultar(Request $request)
{
$entidad = $request['entidad'];
    $result = exec("python3 /root/TFGArchivos/ScriptFinal.py -o $entidad");

    $opiniones = array();
    $palabras = array();
    foreach (json_decode($result) as $valor) {
        if ($valor == 1 || $valor == -1) {
            $opiniones[] = $valor;
        }
        else {
            $palabras[] = $valor;
        }
    }

    return view("resultado_entidad", ['entidad'=>$request['entidad'],"palabras"=>$palabras]);
}
```

And here´s my view´s code:

```
<div id="nube" name="nube" style="width: 550px; height: 350px; position: relative;"></div>

<script>
window.onload = function () 
{
var array = <?php echo json_encode($palabras); ?>;
$("#nube").jQCloud(array);
}
</script>
```

If I declare an array in Javascript and a pass that array to the jQcloud, it works perfect.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked what the rendered output code is?

Comment: What is the output of `echo json_encode($palabras)` ?

Comment: Te result of that python script is something like this:

    [1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,{text: 'quejamos', weight:1},{text: 'replantearse', weight:1},{text: 'orgullo', weight:1},{text: 'solucion', weight:1},{text: 'reclamos', weight:1},{text: 'alcanza', weight:1},{text: 'pesar', weight:1},{text: 'ahre', weight:1}"]

Comment: @JoaquinPerea Can you please share the `$palabras` content after the `foreach` loop? and also share the content of `array` in the JS before calling the `jQCloud`

Comment: The content of $palabras after foreach is:

Array ( [0] => {text: 'deben', weight:1} [1] => {text: 'acabo', weight:1} [2] => {text: 'texto', weight:1} [3] => {text: 'arrepiento', weight:1} [4] => {text: 'quichua', weight:2} ... ) ;

Te content of array before jQCloud calling is:

{text: 'cs', weight:1},{text: 'adelante', weight:2},{text: 'acosar', weight:1},{text: 'traves', weight:1},{text: 'aviso', weight:1},{text: 'voy', weight:8},{text: 'priv', weight:1}...

I post here a short version of both because they are too long.

Comment: Nobody is gonna help me? :(